# HP Vertica, can we install it on Windows & the SQL we use for oracle is same for the HP Vertica?

Tags: database, linux, oracle, vertica

I am new to HP Vertica. I read the installation documentation for the HP Vertica.
The documentation is totally based on the *ix environment. So, my question is **Can we install HP Vertica on Windows also ?**

The other thing, as far as the commands I searched, these are same as the Oracle SQL commands. So, **do we use the same SQL commands for the HP Vertica also ?**

The other concept about the cluster, instance, node, database that I understood is,

```
HOST: is a computer where the Vertica is installed.

INSTANCE: it is also a computer where the Vertica is in running state. 

Node: it is the combination of HOST & INSTANCE.

CLUSTER: I am not clear about this. May be this is about the instances of Vertica running on different computers.

DATABASE: It is the actual installed database software where the data & catalog resides to which other nodes are connected (not sure abt this also).
```

Please help me understand the concepts, If anyone knows it well.

Comment: Please also let me know about, what are the linux clusters. I have an idea about the database clusters.

Comment: Hi Aditya, try dba.stackexchange.com, I think that is the best place for this kind of questions

Comment: Ok. thank you. mucio. I am new to the StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

Vertica only works on Linux, and only some flavors of Linux are supported officially (can't support everything).

Vertica's SQL is based on PostgreSQL.

1 Vertica instance runs over multiple nodes acting in parallel. All of them together constitute the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

you should install a Linux virtual machine on Windows and run Vertica on the virtual machine [as explained here](http://www.howtogeek.com/170870/5-ways-to-run-linux-software-on-windows/)